# I have two python installed on mac , one on usr/bin/python other on /library/frameworks/python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal

i am on a mac, i am trying to get the issue of fixing my path as a module wasnt being read when i ran a python script.

i found out i have two sets of pythons install how could i eliminate this and fix my issue?

i will provide the commands i have ran on terminal ::

-

```
$ python

Python 2.7.10 

$ python3

Python 3.7.3 

$ which python

/usr/bin/python

which python3

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3


echo $PATH

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin


which -a python python3

/usr/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3


which -a python python

/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

---

will there be an issue when running python scripts when i have two locations? , is my path wrong? what would be the best practice!

thanks

Comment: Or if possible any way to completely wipe out both versions of python and start again?  i believe the pip files are installed on the \library\  path

Comment: NVMMM -- I've just cleared all paths that were saved on my bash profile.